# Pandas convert dataframe to array of tuples without None

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analysing some data with Apriori algorithm. This requires me to convert the dataframe into an array of tuples, with each tuple corresponding to a "row" of the dataframe.

```
In [1]: data
Out[1]: 
     c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
r1   a    b    c    d    None
r2   a    b    c    None None
```

I have tried the code below, but there's still some "None" in it. I want to remove them.

```
In [2]: data = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
Out[2]: 
[('a','b','c','d',None),('a','b','c',None,None)]
```

I expect the data like this:

```
[('a','b','c','d'),('a','b','c')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with filtering:

```
data = [tuple([y for y in x if y is not None]) for x in data.values]
print (data)
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Slowier alternative if large data - reshape for remove `None`s and aggregate by first level of `MultiIndex` for tuples:

```
data = data.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(tuple).tolist()
print (data)
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `filter` inside our comprehension to achieve the desired result. Just make sure that your `None`'s are not strings for this to work.

```
data = [tuple(filter(None, x)) for x in data.values]

print(data)
# [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of filtering out the `None`'s is:

```
data_without_none = [tuple(row[row != None]) for row in data.values]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method could be using transpose + apply():

```
df.T.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.dropna())).tolist()
```